# A-Frame v.0.9.x Animation pause camera

Tags: aframe

How is it now possible to stop the camera mouse interaction on animation with camera rotation!?
Until v.0.8.x it was possible with:

```
camera.pause();
... animation ...
camera.play();
```

or:

```
camera.components['look-controls'].data.enabled = false;
... animation ...
camera.components['look-controls'].data.enabled = true;
```

But this trick doesn't work anymore, as the animation doesn't start.

PS: A camera wrapper does not seem to help either.

Comment: Hard to tell without link to runnable example. FYI, don’t access component data directly but use `setAttribute(‘look-controls’, ‘enabled’, false)` https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/introduction/javascript-events-dom-apis.html#updating-a-component-with-setattribute

Comment: By the way, answers can be posted in the answers section.

Answer (score 0):

https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/introduction/javascript-events-dom-apis.html#updating-a-component-with-setattribute

`camera.setAttribute(‘look-controls’, ‘enabled’, false)`